# Android app crashes in 5.0 and above when using MediaPlayer with url

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing an android app which play a mp3 songs by using a remote url. everything is working fine in android devices below api 5.0.But when starting app in samsung s5(5.1) it suddenly crashes

mu logcat is giving error "QCmediaPlayer mediaplayer is not present.Here is my code of Media Player

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnPreparedListener   {
    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;
    private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL ="https://aryaradio.s3.amazonaws.com/";
    private String KEYNAME,encodedurl;
    private List<String> playlistarray;
    private List<MediaPlayer> mplayerList;
    private ImageButton buttonPlay;
    private List<S3ObjectSummary> playlist=null;
    private ImageButton buttonStopPlay;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    URL url,currentsongurl;
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private AmazonS3Client mClient;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        playlistarray=new ArrayList<String>();
        mplayerList=new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            mClient = Util.getS3Client(MainActivity2.this);
            initializeUIElements();
            //new RefreshTask().execute();
            buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this)
                .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setMessage(
                    getResources().getString(
                        R.string.internet_error))
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void initializeUIElements() {
        buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Play);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStopPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Stop);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity2.class));
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Message");
        progress.setMessage("Loading Song ...");
        progress.setCancelable(true);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.show();

        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progress.dismiss();
                player.start();
                player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        try {
                           // player.setNextMediaPlayer(mplayerList.get(2));
                            stopPlaying();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        killMediaPlayer();
        initializeMediaPlayer(playlistarray);
        buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer(List<String> playlist) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        int noOfSongs=playlist.size();
        String url = "https://aryaradio.s3.amazonaws.com/us-east-1:eb604ac1-c4e3-4226-bea8-22f214a6b0b0/RecordingArya-9459.mp3.null";
        try {
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource(url);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```